# In Nest Js I'm using redis cache manager in a request scoped service but it is not reading the expiration

Tags: caching, redis, request, nestjs

I'm using cache manager as explained in the Nest JS docs but the service is request scoped. Initially it couldn't find the cache manager so I moved it from the app module to the local module file and its caching but its not using the set expiration instead its always defaulting to 5000,
I'm checking this in the terminal with TTL locations

This is the call I'm using. It's working fine in a service that isn't request scoped, do I need to be doing something specific for cache management in request scoped services?

```
 await this.cacheManager.set(
    'locations',
    location_data,
      6000
          );
```